# Unable to Change Title in WordPress Dashboard

Tags: tags, title

I am unable to make any changes to my title tag. When I put the cursor on the Title place it automatically hides. I tried to change it through Yoast SEO plugin but still, it is not working. Kindly help me out

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling your plugins and switching to a default theme, so you can figure out what theme or plugin is controlling it?

Comment: Also try another browser, in case you have a browser addon/setting messing it up.